How to protect the Nginx servers from AWS Abuse Report?
I have 2 Nginx servers, each of which serves around 30k domains. For each of the domains, we have SSL certificate present on that server, generated using Let's Encrypt. I map each of the domain there let's say abc.com and its subdomain www.abc.com with IP address of this server as A record. Now, sometimes abuse report comes on any domain from Amazon and if not responded within 24 hours, Amazon blocks the IP.
In that case, I have 2 options:

For all the domains present on that server, change the A record there for a different server using a script, which will be a very heavy operation. Along with that, all the SSL certificates needs to be transferred to a separate server.
Instead of A records, we will set CNAME records for all the domains and its subdomains (e.g. abc.com and www.abc.com) to another server with value, say pqr.xyz.com. And then, we will map that CNAME to the IP of that server at one place in a separate DNS Management in AWS/GCP. With this way, in case, an IP gets blocked by the server, I don't need to change the DNS Records for each domain. Instead, I will update the IP of the old server to new server at that one dedicated server and will transfer the certificates there using automation.

Now with this approach 2, I have a disadvantage that if CNAME records are added on both root domain and subdomain then I won't be able to setup other DNS records like MX, TXT, etc.
I also observed that to integrate domain on Shopify, one has to add A record on root domain and CNAME record to www subdomain. But I am not sure how Shopify protects their domains from AWS Report in that case because the IPs associated with root domain and subdomain are different.
Can anyone please tell what would be the best or better approach here and how to protect my servers in this case?

Your servers are being used to attack other people on the internet and your solution is to hide this from AWS? Really?

@symcbean where did I say that I want to hide from AWS? We take strict action on the domains on which we receive abuse report. It's just that the domains on the same server (due to its IP getting blocked), in which there's no problem also gets affected when we weren't able to take prompt action on the reported domain. I think you misunderstood my point in the post.

Another option is to try Anycast IP. The configuration is as follows: when one node or server is blocked, requests are automatically redirected to another unblocked server with the same IP.

As discussed, you may consider below solution to resolve mentioned issue in your network:
A. Deploy Reverse proxy in your network.
B. Enable NAT64 functionality in network and traffic to be directed towards RP.
C. Transfer all SSL certificate to RP and may configure RP in SSL offloading mode.
D. Consider /64 IPV6 for your websites and allocate 1 IPV6 per domain.
E. Using NAT64 redirect all website traffic to RP which inturn route traffic towards nginx servers.
F. Define AAAA records for all domains in DNS.
Pros of above architecture:

You may identify and isolate malicious domain.
RP can help in deep packet inspection as well along with WAF functionality (as per feature availability).
Architecture can be scaled up or down as per business requirements.
Availability of genuine domains will not be impacted due to malicious domains.
Webservers need not to do SSL offloading work which may provide mileage in resource optimization.
Webservers would not be directly exposed and will get protected from various threats and risks.

Do share your feedback post testing suggested solution.

The solution is to clean up your act.
Your discussion about CNAMES at the base of the domain name break the DNS RFC, so is ill-advised.
My suggestion would be to consider the following partial solutions - which combined will likely provide a fairly robust solution.

Split your websites so you are not hosting as many websites on a single IP address.  This will limit the blast radius of a ban, and also help narrow down the offending site(s).  You can have multiple IP addresses associated with a single web server.

Consider using a reverse proxy service - someone like Cloudflare can probably help with reputation management.

Tighten up your customer base / weed out the bad apples.

Run Antivirus and a WAF or similar to prevent bad actors getting in.   If your sites are Wordpress sites, take measures over and above the standard install to limit the ability of bad actors to exploit problems.

Actually put mechanisms in place to find and respond to breaches pro-actively.  24 hours is a long time.

Look at Alias records.  I don't like them because they are a pseudo record and have lots of limitations - and I suspect they may not be an option - but its worth looking at.

Consider requiring strong passwords and checking these against lists of known breached passwords.

Diversify.  AWS is not the only player in town.  Indeed they are not even the best player for most versions of best.



So, if you think about it, I see two options:

Change the A records and move the certificates to another server (pretty much the same as what you suggested). But yeah, you’ll have to do it for all domains and transfer the certificates. Depends on how many domains you’ve got, of course.

Use CNAME records for all domains and subdomains. If the IP gets blocked, you just change the IP on one server, and all domains will pick up the update.
But keep in mind, the second method has a downside — you won’t be able to set other DNS records for the root domain, like MX for email.


Ideally, you should combine both approaches.

I already listed these 2 solutions in my post. I don't know how your solutions are different from mine.

Yes, I was just clarifying that it is most optimal to use them together
